# Provide partition data based on month using hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have data in text file like:

```
323.81.303.680 - - [25/Oct/2011:01:41:00 -0500] "GET /download/download6.zip HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.19) Gecko/2010031422 Firefox/3.0.19"
```

created table schema for above data using regexserde:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS weblogs (
  host STRING,
   identity STRING,
   apache_user STRING,
   time STRING,
   request STRING,
   status STRING,
   size STRING,
   referer STRING,
   agent STRING
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
"input.regex" = "([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) (-|\\[[^\\]]*\\]) ([^ \"]*|\"[^\"]*\") (-|[0-9]*) (-|[0-9]*)(?: ([^ \"]*|\"[^\"]*\") ([^ \"]*|\"[^\"]*\"))?",
"output.format.string" = "%1$s %2$s %3$s %4$s %5$s %6$s %7$s %8$s %9$s"
) 
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

and loaded the data properly

but here the problem is I need to Provide the partition data based on monthly

im getting time : `[25/Oct/2011:01:41:00 -0500]` as string.

I need to partition the data based on monthly, above time field is string type so please any one helps me to partition the all the data based on year and month wise.

Comment: `"output.format.string"` is deprecated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select  time
       ,unix_timestamp(time,'[dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss z]')                                                                                                         
       ,from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(time,'[dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss z]'))
       ,to_utc_timestamp(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(time,'[dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss z]')),'PST')
       ,date_format(to_utc_timestamp(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(time,'[dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss z]')),'PST'),'YYYY-MM') 

from    weblogs
;
```

---

```
+------------------------------+---------------+---------------------+----------------------------+---------+
|             time             |      c1       |         c2          |             c3             |   c4    |
+------------------------------+---------------+---------------------+----------------------------+---------+
| [25/Oct/2011:01:41:00 -0500] | 1,319,524,860 | 2011-10-24 23:41:00 | 2011-10-25 06:41:00.000000 | 2011-10 |
+------------------------------+---------------+---------------------+----------------------------+---------+
```

Comment: the partition is dynamic, instead of static providing 25/Oct/2011:01:41:00 -0500 can i use time feild there

Comment: how im trying it showing null values:                                                                                     select  date_format(to_utc_timestamp(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('time','dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss z')),'PST'),'YYYY-MM') as `yyyy-mm` from access_log limit 10;
OK
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
Time taken: 0.222 seconds, Fetched: 10 row(s)

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong. Check the updated answer.

Comment: select  time(to_utc_timestamp(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('[dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss z]')),'PST'),'YYYY-MM') as `yyyy-mm`from access_log limit 10;
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10011]: Line 1:8 Invalid function 'time'

Comment: Check again now

Comment: here time is feild of access_log, i'm selecting time feild from table access_log but its show semantic error

Comment: This is a tested solution based on the table definition and the data sample you had supplied

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe not found

Comment: Seriously? What happened to "created table ... and loaded the data properly"?

Comment: no while loading im getting error like:    Diagnostic Messages for this Task:
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
 at